# Issue related to using Split function in Famo.us

Tags: famo.us

i have small application in Famo.us

I have following code..

```
draggable.on('update',function(data){
        var pos =data.position;
        var t = pos.split(",");
});
```

In above code, data.position return result in `x,y`  format,
i just want to check x value whether it is greater than 0 or not. For that i have used split function. but it doesn't work..

How to use Split and substring functions in Famp.us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that data.position returns an array and not a string..

You could do the following to get the x position.. Hope it helps!

```
draggable.on('update',function(data){
    var pos = data.position;
    var x = pos[0];
    var y = pos[1];
});
```